# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app.model'

Tags: python, ipython

I just tried to `import app.model.preprocessor` and it gave me the following error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app.model'

I am using code from a tutorial. Does anyone know why my computer doesn't want to import `app.model`? I did install app with pip3.

[image: import and error]

Comment: Did you try importing just `app`?

Comment: this pip module app does not have app.model. which tutorial are you following ?

Comment: @mbieren I'm following Siraj Raval's Tutorial. You can find it on this git: https://github.com/llSourcell/Convolutional_neural_network. The code is on the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured it out. App is a class written by Siraj. I didn't pull the entire git because I thought this was just using frameworks. Sorry! 
So the git contains an app folder with a model folder inside. So it's not the 'app' that is publicly accessible as a framework.